# Sigasi Eclipse "Codometer" half hidden

Tags: eclipse, widget, settings, toolbar, sigasi-studio

I'm using a Sigasi eclipse plug in to program and simulate VHDL through Eclipse. However, at present I'n only using the free version, which supports projects up to a certain size. This size is handily indicated by a provided "codometer" widget in the bottom left hand corner - however, its half hidden and a lot of the time unreadable - see picture!

Despite using the drag bar to move it around - I only ever see half of the number and I can't read it well enough to see how much space I have - is there a setting in Eclipse or Sigasi to fix this ? It doesn't cause any problems itself but has become very irritating!

Thanks,

David

[image]

Comment: This is more a software tools question than a VHDL language question. The SIGASI folks seem very helpful, I'd use their own help system.

Comment: It is yes...that's why I've put the eclipse, toolbar, widget and setting tag. Vhdl tag is simply because I use it for vhdl but I'll remove it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(If anybody else ever has this problem)
Not a complete solution to this (despite spending several hours going through Eclipse settings!), but as an intermediary, I found by chance that if you hover your mouse over the partially displayed widget it gives a breakdown of how much space you have used out of your 32kB project size limit - as shown below.

[image]